# Dynamic data is not sending via sendgrid web api using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, sendgrid

I am trying to send dynamic data from NodeJs in sendgrid web api email templates but unable to send.

It is showing something like this below in email where I want to show dynamic data:

```
" _
```

This is my node js code below:

```
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);

const msg = {

to: req.body.email,
from: 'trav@gmail.com',
templateId:'d-8e322d7da4f44ca1afc76aefb3725555',
substitutionWrapppers:['{{" , "}}'],
substitutions:
{
  company_name:'Example',
  state:'Rajasthan'
}

sgMail.send(msg, (err) => {

                            if(err){

                                 console.log("Error", err);
                            }else{

                                 console.log("Email sent");
                                }
                            });
```

In send grid email template below:

```
{{company}}  {{state}}
```

Someone please let me know what I am doing wrong.Any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, its working fine problem was in setting dynamic data in nodejs app and make substitution wrapper global.

Here is an updated code:

```
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');

sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
sgMail.setSubstitutionWrappers("{{", "}}");

const msg = {

to: req.body.email,
from: 'trav@gmail.com',
templateId:'d-8e322d7da4f44ca1afc76aefb3725555',
dynamicTemplateData: {

      company_name: 'Example',
      state: 'Rajasthan'
}

sgMail.send(msg, (err) => {

                        if(err){

                             console.log("Error", err);
                        }else{

                             console.log("Email sent");
                            }
                        });
```

**THANKS**